# How can a table append the collapse class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

```
 list_of_tasks.forEach(function (t) {

  tbody.append(
 $(document.createElement("tr")).append(
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.task_id),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.task_status),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.task_operator),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.number_of_hits),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.finished_hits),
        $(document.createElement("td")).append(
           $(document.createElement("button"))
                .addClass("btn btn-primary")
                .attr("type", "button")
                .attr("data-toggle", "collapse")
                .attr("data-target", "#collapseExample")
                .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
                .attr("aria-controls", "collapseExample")
                .text("show task results")
              )
           )
      );

 });
```

Currently, I create a table, each row of the table has a button, if you click the button, the collapse class with id collapseExmaple will appear and show the text. How could this table append the collapse class, with something like cellspan?

```
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
       <div class="well" id="collapseExmaplewell"> 
       </div>
  </div>
```

I am new  to Javascript.

Comment: Are you reusing IDs? That would be invalid as IDs must be unique.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What does "append a class" mean? Append an element with that class?

Comment: @isherwood, yes, I reused the id, so currently, #collapseExample always show the last row's results. I hope by click the button, it transfer a value(tasked) to the #collapseExample, #collapseExample show the corresponding results. Or otherwise, I need to generate several collapse classes, but i do not know the exactly number, in this situation, the table should append the collapse in the forEach(function(t)), that is what I am asking for. Thx –

Comment: or precisely, how can I add the on click(function()) to the document.createElement("button")?                   .attr("onclick", "function()") does not work~~ not sure if onclick  can be used together with collapse